# NullPointerException when invoking the mockito mocked function

Tags: junit, java-8, mockito

I have below method in my code

```
 public <T> T doHttpPost(String url, String data, BiFunction<String, Integer, T> responseHandler, Consumer<Exception> exceptionHandler) {
...
}
```

The above method is used as below

```
return APIClient.doHttpPost(url, EmptyString, null, null);
```

Even when trying to pass methods instead of nulls to the 2 arguments above, i am still getting the error

During writing my unit test methods, I am using the mock which is setup as below,

```
doAnswer(ans -> true).when(apiClient).doHttpPost(anyString(), anyString(), any(BiFunction.class), any(Consumer.class));
doAnswer(ans -> true).when(apiClient).doHttpPost(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), any(BiFunction.class), any(Consumer.class));
```

However, the null pointer exception still occurred, hence I tried to change the above as below in the mock setup and still getting the null pointer exception

```
when(apiClient.doHttpPost(anyString(), anyString(), any(BiFunction.class), any(Consumer.class))).thenReturn(true);
when(apiClient.doHttpPost(anyString(), any(HttpEntity.class), any(BiFunction.class), any(Consumer.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

The mock setup for other regular methods are working fine, they have no generic implementations.

When I checked the method call in the watch window in IntelliJ IDE, i found that the method returns null instead of true which is configured in the mock. If there is a way to find why these 2 methods in the mock are not setup correctly, it will be easy for fixing

**EDIT**
Based on the suggestion by @Marco, I have tried the following

```
doAnswer(ans -> true).when(apiClient).doHttpPost(anyString(), anyString(), any(), any());
```

when using the below invocation methods,

```
return jenkinsAPIClient.doHttpPost(url, EmptyString, null, null);
```

The test fails with the below error

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
APIClient#0 bean.doHttpPost(
    <any string>,
    <any string>,
    <any java.util.function.BiFunction>,
    <any java.util.function.Consumer>
);
testcasename(ServiceTests.java:435)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
APIClient#0 bean.doHttpPost(
    "nulljob/CL217R/job/One/doRename?newName=aYbf8y8FRirlgXQoz7ySNhQqNp870xY0tZ9O6sSSBlbfgktoM7zb3UNdMNbKMQM9amMLio9KMzLtoOmnuj9z0wvA72h1L8oSGbLVqQQbmso4PTXMhFMfc14we03",
    "",
    null,
    null
);
```

In case, I use the below method call,

```
return jenkinsAPIClient.doHttpPost(url, EmptyString, jenkinsAPIClient.successStatusCheck, jenkinsAPIClient.GenericExceptionHandler);
```

The test case fails with the below error

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
APIClient#0 bean.doHttpPost(
    <any string>,
    <any string>,
    <any java.util.function.BiFunction>,
    <any java.util.function.Consumer>
);
testcasename(ServiceTests.java:435)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
APIClient#0 bean.doHttpPost(
    "nulljob/CL217R/job/One/doRename?newName=aYbf8y8FRirlgXQoz7ySNhQqNp870xY0tZ9O6sSSBlbfgktoM7zb3UNdMNbKMQM9amMLio9KMzLtoOmnuj9z0wvA72h1L8oSGbLVqQQbmso4PTXMhFMfc14we03",
    "",
    null,
    APIClient$$Lambda$128/2000563893@360bc645
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `null` as a agrs in the method that isn't a String or object is a simple null for that reason you need to mock the call in the following way:

```
doAnswer(ans -> true).when(apiClient).doHttpPost(anyString(), anyString(), any(), any());
```

With only Mockito.any() should work because works with anything including nulls.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have updated the post with the trials and the error messages, can you please check the same and suggest the change.